# Is there any way to reduce computation time of Spreadsheet.makeCopy() in this setting?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I have a working script that contains the following code in a method of a custom class:

```
destination = this
  ._source
  .makeCopy(
    this._name,
    this._folder
  )
  .setStarred(true);
```

This script is taking approximately 15 seconds to complete. `this._source` is an instance of DriveApp.File (`DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxxxxxxxxx')`) of the template file the user is working with. `this._name` is simply a string created by tacking the year onto the title. 'this._folder' is an instance of DriveApp.Folder (`DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxx')`). All of these except for `destination` are instantiated when the class is instantiated in my On Open trigger, long before the user begins making the copy, while `destination` is instantiated at the beginning of this method (though I measured that instantiation to be pretty fast).

I measured 15380 milliseconds before and after this statement. I isolated `DriveApp.File.setStarred()` and measured 100 milliseconds, so the problem is down to `DriveApp.File.makeCopy()`. Is there anything I can do to get a faster result? I tried the various versions of `.makeCopy`, and they all seemed to take a while. I think the problem is the size of my actual file (178 KB, which I believe is fairly large for a Sheets file). It has 13 Sheets, one for the entire year's revenue numbers, and twelve months of daily reconciliation for cash drawers, the safe, and bank deposits/withdrawals, so it has a myriad of formulas in it.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I ran "Make a Copy" from Google Drive context menu and took the same amount of time. So I'm guessing there's no way to do this without reducing file size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SUGGESTION:**

You could try [Drive API V2 Files:copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy) method. Initially tested this on a 280kb sheets file which resulted in 11000 milliseconds in computation time using the API Explorer.

Comment: This worked great for me, thanks. Took me a minute to read through the documentation, but there was a drastic difference in speed.

Answer (score 1):

#### Not sure if it's faster all of the time but it seems faster to me

```
function makeCopy() {
  var folderid = "dfolderid";
  var fileid = "fileid";
  var folder = Drive.Files.get(folderid, { "supportsAllDrives": true });
  var newFile = { "fileId": fileid, "parents": [folder] };
  var args = { "resource": { "parents": [folder], "title": "new Title" }, "supportsAllDrives": true };
  Drive.Files.copy(newFile, fileid, args);
}
```